# Including an html email editor (similar to gmail send form) in my appscript GUI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a google-sheets add-on that does some data processing and allows a user to send and edit an email with the final result. A number of gsuite add-ons with email functionality appear to have an exact clone of the email draft form from Gmail, so i am wondering if it's possible to include the gmail email draft form or have these add-ons simply replicated the UI in their own code?

Comment: Your question is probably considered to be "off-topic" to Stack Overflow because it's asking about general information, and not about a specific line of code.  It's probably better to ask this type of question in the Apps Script community at: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Gmail UI compose draft windows by using `GmailApp.createDraft` [1] function for an empty draft, or you can get a specific message or thread you want to reply to and use the `createDraft` function for that class, these functions are mentioned in the documentation [2].

Implementing the code and steps from Gmail Add-on quickstart [3] and compose draft guide [2], I got the below code working as an Add-on with a button that when clicked it'll open a draft reply to the email you have opened:

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

  // Create a section
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
  .setHeader("<font color=\"#1257e0\"><b>Create email draft reply</b></font>"); 

  // Action to trigger createReplyDraft funciton
  var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
  .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');

  // Create button to trigger action when clicked
  var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText('Compose Reply')
  .setComposeAction(composeAction, CardService.ComposedEmailType.STANDALONE_DRAFT);

  // Add the button widget to the section.
  section.addWidget(composeButton);

  // Build the main card after adding the section.
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
             .setTitle('Create draft response')
             .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_48dp.png'))
  .addSection(section)
  .build();

  return [card];
}

/**
*  Creates a draft email (with an attachment and inline image)
*  as a reply to an existing message.
*  @param {Object} e data passed by the action.
*  @return {ComposeActionResponse}
*/
function createReplyDraft(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
  // a reply to be drafted.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  // Creates a draft reply.
  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var draft = message.createDraftReply('', {
    htmlBody: "Kitten!"
  })
  // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
  // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
  // above.
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
  .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}
```

Be sure to have in the manifest the necessary scopes for the functions you're using.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body

[2] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/compose#reply_drafts

[3] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/quickstart